# Selecting property A of an element with property B

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

**Description**:

I am selecting multiple inputs with **querySelectorAll()**:

`y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('#form input[name="fname"], #form input[name="lname"], #form input[name="dname"]');`

Iterating over each of the input fields returned by **querySelectorAll()** and checking if the value of `fname` and the value of `lname` or the value of `dname` are empty:

```
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

    if (y[i]."fname".value == "" && y[i]."lname".value == "" || y[i]."dname".value == "") {

      y[i].className += " invalid";

      valid = false;
    }
}
```

The whole function is as follows:

```
function validateForm() {

  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('#form input[name="fname"], #form input[name="lname"], #form input[name="dname"]');

  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

    if (y[i]."fname".value == "" && y[i]."lname".value == "" || y[i]."dname".value == "") {

      y[i].className += " invalid";

      valid = false;
    }
  }

  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Now in the if statement, I want to say: **check if the value of the attribute** `value` **of the element with attribute called name that is** `fname` **is empty**.

Sample input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">
```

Comment: I read the text in bold 5 times now and still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: @BoltKey I want to select an element by its name attribute and check the value of that element. So if my input field is: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="test">` I want to select the input via `fname` and check if the element with `fname` has a `value` of `test`.

Comment: @BoltKey Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Keeper/11y1dcd2/1/ . Notice line #50 of the javascript. It checks if any of the inputs is empty. I want to have a different condition there. Like check if input A is empty or if input B is empty.